# Windows web browser which supports offline migration of all stored data

Tags: windows, web-browser, migration

I'm on Windows and am using a lot of google-chrome instances with `--user-data-dir` and tried to transfer all of them to a new pc (settings, open tabs, saved passwords, cookies, history, ...) and a different windows user account.

Most of them are not associated with any google account, so sync is not an option. Unfortunately, manually copying the folders to the new pc doesn't work or would be very complex because some things are encrypted.

I'm looking for a different windows web browser which supports such a scenario without the need to create online accounts for migration but using only offline tools or preferably simple file copy.

Answer (score 2):

One possible combination is Firefox + [MozBackup](https://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/).

MozBackup offer you the options to backup/restore any of the profiles in Firefox. The result is one file which can be easy transferred to other PC. For the fact the backup file is zip so you can easy open it and extract any file if required. You can protect each backup archive with password.

Firefox simplify the usage of more than one profile, you can just run (command line or batch/shell file) `firefox -p name_of_the_profile` and run specific one.

Comment: This works great! It's remarkable that this >10 years old pascal app still works such well.